# Aurelia binding a string to a template through a custom element

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to create a dropdown component that is easily reusable. I would like to know if it is possible to do something like so:

```
<dropdown title.bind="Projects"></dropdown>
```

Notice I am passing a string "Projects" not a JS object. Then my dropdown template have:

```
<template>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">${title}</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</template>
```

Of course I am not looping the dropdown-items in my demo code yet (future to do). Notice I am trying to use title like so `<a>${title}</a>` in the template.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a simple bindable in `dropdown`'s view model but when setting the value to a plain string, don't use `.bind`:

```
<dropdown title="Projects"></dropdown>
```

When you are using `title.bind`, Aurelia binder engine will try to parse it as an expression and fail, since you (probably) don't have `Projects` property in your current context.

Comment: Brilliant, I knew I was doing this wrong. I was wrapping in quotes like `blah.bind="'Some random string'"` which is not very good.